# How do you say “I drove to the mountains” vs “I drove in the mountains”?

Tags: translation

How do you say

> I drove to the mountains

vs

> I drove in the mountains

?

In google translate they both are

> Ich bin in die Berge gefahren

Answer (score 7):

The two statements precisely reflect the difference between dative and accusative for certain prepositions (including *in*) in German:

---

> I drove to the mountains

indicates a direction/destination and therefore uses the accusative case:

> Ich bin in die Berge gefahren.

---

> I drove in the mountains

indicates a location where the action took place and therefore uses the dative case:

> Ich bin in den Bergen gefahren.

(Note that the latter sounds slightly incomplete because "fahren" on its own is somewhat indefinite in German. You may want to use "Auto fahren" (here: "Auto gefahren") to come closer to the English "to drive".)

Comment: For me, even '_in den Bergen Auto gefahren_' sounds strange, but perhaps the English version is similarly unusual. Anyway, as for me '_in den Bergen Auto fahren_' is pragmatically doubtful, I translated it in a way that perhaps doesn't correspond to the English sentence but is at least normal German. Would you say "_Ich gehe / ich fahre (Auto) in der Stadt_"?

Comment: @RalfJoerres: Yes, why wouldn't I? "Ich bin an Ampeln und Staus gewöhnt, weil ich häufig in der Stadt Auto fahre."; "Ich bin gestern in den Bergen Auto gefahren, abends war mir ganz schwindelig von den Serpentinen."

Comment: Nevertheless for me '_ich bin häufig in der Stadt mit dem Auto unterwegs_' sounds more natural than '_ich fahre häufig in der Stadt Auto_'. An isolated '_ich fahre in der Stadt_' is completely anacceptable. The reason is that _fahren_ as well as _gehen_ need local complements naming the destinations of the movement. If you just want to talk about the activity of driving without destination you normally change the predicate, and for me the most normal one would be '_mit einem Fahrzeug irgendwo unterwegs sein_'. Beside that, an uncompleted _fahren_ means _nicht (zu Fuß) laufen_.

Comment: @RalfJoerres: "Nevertheless for me '_ich bin häufig in der Stadt mit dem Auto unterwegs_' sounds more natural than '_ich fahre häufig in der Stadt Auto_'." - if, for some reason, you need to express that it's *you* who drives, "mit dem Auto unterwegs" leaves a bit of ambiguity, otherwise the two options appear to me as equally acceptable. "An isolated '_ich fahre in der Stadt_' is completely anacceptable." - I agree, this usually follows some context, such as a sentence that already establishes what kind (vehicle) of "fahren" is meant.

Comment: In some situations, the ambiguity you are talking about is resolved by '_am Steuer sitzen_' or '_selbst fahren_', but, talking about _Ampeln_ and _Staus_ I suppose one would understand that the situation is seen from a driver's perspective. You are right, that's not absolutely 'clean-cut'.

Answer (score 0):

I drove *to the mountains* = *Ich bin in die Berge gefahren* - um z.B. Urlaub zu machen, oder für ein Wochenende.

I drove *in the mountains* = ***Ich war mit dem Auto in den Bergen unterwegs.***